adb query mediastore for image and other objects on newer Android devices
I want to open images, audio and video files on a remote Android device by using adb commands. I got commands from here: https://github.com/Linuxndroid/ADB-Cheat-Sheet . The remote device is not rooted and has a newer Android version (API 25+), so I must access the media by using Android content provider (MediaStore).
This command does NOT work on newer devices because of security:
adb shell am start -t image/* -d file:///sdcard/myfile.jpg

I can open a media file if I exactly know the media number (here 51382) like this:
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -t images/* -d content://media/external/images/media/51382

How can I get the media number (here 51382) via adb? I tryed using...
adb shell content query... 

...but I can't find out. Often I get a permission error.
How is it possible to open medias on a newer remote device by adb? How to get their media number?
